# Listbox is adding too many entries

Tags: visual-studio-2013

What I want is for this program to do is to show Microsoft Outlook 2010 in "installed" listbox if it's installed and "notinstalled" if it's not installed.  "listbox1" has a list of all installed applications in it on form load.

The issue is that while it does work for the "installed" portion, it lists the application many times in the "notinstalled" box.  I only want it to show up once.

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

```
    Dim regkey, subkey As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey
    Dim value As String
    Dim regpath As String = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
    regkey = My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(regpath)
    Dim subkeys() As String = regkey.GetSubKeyNames
    Dim includes As Boolean
    For Each subk As String In subkeys
        subkey = regkey.OpenSubKey(subk)
        value = subkey.GetValue("DisplayName", "")
        If value <> "" Then
            includes = True
            If value.IndexOf("Hotfix") <> -1 Then includes = False
            If value.IndexOf("Security Update") <> -1 Then includes = False
            If value.IndexOf("Update for") <> -1 Then includes = False
            If includes = True Then ListBox1.Items.Add(value)
        End If
    Next

    Dim count As Integer = (ListBox1.Items.Count - 1)
    Dim words As String
    Dim softName As String


    softName = "Microsoft Outlook 2010"
    For a = 0 To count
        words = ListBox1.Items.Item(a)
        If InStr(words.ToLower, softName.ToLower) Then
            Installed.Items.Add(words)
        Else
            NotInstalled.Items.Add(softName)
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

The repeating string is due to a simple error due to the call to `NotInstalled.Items.Add(softName)`  for each item inspected. You probably want to add it only at the end of the loop.

However you could simplify your code with a bit of Linq

```
Dim result = words.Where(Function(x) x.ToLower().IndexOf("microsoft outlook 2010") >= 0)
if result IsNot Nothing then
    Installed.Items.AddRange(result.ToArray)
else
    NotInstalled.Items.Add(softName)
end if
```

But you should consider some problems in your code. If Outlook is installed as part of Office there is not an entry for it in the uninstall section. Then there is the problem of the automatic redirection to different section of the registry if you are running on a 64bit system. And what if your Outlook is a 32bit version installed on a 64bit system and your app run in AnyCPU mode? It is not a trivial task to account for all these possibility. Just to warn you

Comment: From reading the question it looks like he only wants Outlook added to either the of the two lists. This would add every item that is not Outlook to the NotInstalled list.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try something like. (I'm a c# guy, so I hope my syntax is right.)

```
Dim isOutlookInstalled = False

softName = "Microsoft Outlook 2010"
For a = 0 To count
    words = ListBox1.Items.Item(a)
    If InStr(words.ToLower, softName.ToLower) Then
        Installed.Items.Add(words)
    End If
Next
If isOutlookInstalled <> True
    NotInstalled.Items.Add(softName)
End If
```